"get out of the house" breath group, intermission making any change in the meaning?

Get out of the house!

I think 'get' alone makes no sense. So 'get out' makes a meaning: Don't be here.
'of the house' sounds like 'from the house' because the preceding 'get out' gives context.
In this case, I think I can make intermission(a brief stop) between 'Get out' and 'of the house'.
That being said, many natives speakers of English say this sentence by way of just only one breath group: without intermission. Or they pronounce it like 'out of' is a one word.
If I say "Get out /(pause)/ of the house, does this sound idiomatic or make sense? Or
Should I say "Get out of (no pause) the house"? You know, 'out of' even sounds like 'out a'

No, it's not idiomatic to add a pause anywhere in this sentence.

It's relatively unlikely, but exclamatory imperative "Get!" (or "Git!") can occur as a standalone utterance. So can "Out!" and "Out of the house!", either or both of which could in principle follow as separate / consecutive utterances. But that's at the margins. If you're just learning how Anglophones normally speak, you don't need to learn that. But it's probably worth noting that in a context like "Get out of the house!", out of is very often reduced to outta, and quite often reduced to just out (the preposition of is "swallowed" into inaudibility).

Yes, get out is a meaningful combination, but so is out of. The sentence just means "Leave the house!", so there is no reason to make a pause in it.

Since of the house is complement to out, the command should be said in a single breath, that is, with no syntactic pause long enough to isolate of the house from out.
That's assuming you are in direct communication and there is no miscommunication.  Normal face-to-face conversation, such as a parent telling a child to go outside and play.
But let's say you're a spy communicating via radio into an earphone worn by a spy colleague inside the house.  You can see the spy enter a room and through the window of an adjacent room you can see an enemy spy about to set a huge bomb to go off in 20 seconds, like in the movies:

00:20... 00:19... 00:18...

You yell into your radio:

Get out of the house!

but there's some static on the line and your spy colleague backs out of the room  but only as far as the hallway. So now you yell:

Get out {isolating pause} of the HOUSE!

This time you do pause in order to isolate "of the house" for clarity, putting the prepositional phrase in its own spotlight, as it were, and you come down loud and heavy on the word HOUSE.

The phrase should be spoken without pauses.

If I say "Get out /(pause)/ of the house, does this sound idiomatic or make sense?

99% of the time - absolutely not.
1% of the time - we can discuss that.
You may just say "Get out!"
That's sufficient and means "Don't be here".
If you say "get out", and pause, the expression is finished and complete.  To add "of the house" later would be clarifying the meaning, by explaining "out of where?"  "out of what?".
Most of the time that's well understood by both the speaker and the listener.
So it would be very unusual to communicate your message "Get out" and then add a thoughtful clarification, in case they didn't understand what you meant.
It's all said together in one breath group, with one meaning.
The 1% case that I mentioned earlier is if there is genuinely a confusion between "out of the room" and "out of the house".  This would be rare.  If such an ambiguity existed, then you might pause in the sentence.
